# Random Additional LineItem appearing in a membership sign up form

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, line-items

3 Additional LineItems have just been spotted in one of our membership sign up forms (for organisations) - though they have never been set up (I don't know how such things would be set up), and don't appear on any settings page.  The amounts section is no enabled for the contribution page (because it is being used for memberships).

Does anyone have any ideas how this is happening, and how we might remove them?

Frontend[image]

Backend[image]

Comment: Do you have access to access to database?

Comment: Do you have Lineitem editor extension installed?

Comment: Yes, both access to database and Lineitem editor is installed

Comment: Disabling Lineitem editor (and clearing caches etc) doesn't appear to remove the problem.  However with further testing it appears to be only showing to 'Admin' level users and not Anonymous or our Member level user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to run below query to disable the field so that they don't appear on screen. Deleting the field is little risky as you may end up creating screwing financial data.

```
UPDATE civicrm_price_field cpf 
INNER JOIN civicrm_price_set_entity cpse
  ON cpse.entity_table = 'civicrm_contribution_page'
    AND cpse.price_set_id = cpf.price_set_id
    AND cpf.html_type <> 'Radio'
    AND cpse.entity_id = 4
SET cpf.is_active = 0;
```

Note: Replace 4 with contribution/membership page id.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.